# Texture blurry when viewed at shallow angle

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

I have this mesh with a full size texture added on one side. When I look at the texture at a shallow angle, texture further from view point gets extremely blurry, almost like I have some kind of depth of field filter on

How do I get my texture 100% sharp?

[image: Sharp / blurry texture]

Comment: Does it looks blurry when its actually rendered? With the same view you have now hit shift+z and see if it sharpens up

Comment: There is no need for salutations/ greetings/ or thanks. You can thank someone by accepting and upvoting their answer - leaving the extra words in the post adds very little in terms of usefulness for future users who may find this question from a search engine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are caused by [Mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap), it is an optimization technique to improve performance and rendering speed of the viewport. It works by automatically creating several copies of used image textures at different resolutions or sizes in GPU memory to speed up rendering.

The blurring is an unintentional side effect of the lower resolution used at larger distances or grazing angles. It is harmless and affects the viewport only, it will **not** affect your final render image.

If you don't like it you can deactivate them in *User Preferences > System > OpenGL > Mipmaps* or control GPU generation.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The reason Mipmaps are around in the first place is because sometimes you want the blurred image since it represents "the average" pixel value rather than the "exact pixel at this one point" -- noisy textures will look grainy or flicker in motion (temporal aliasing).

If you don't have issues with grain or flicker, you can turn off Mipmapping in the UserPreferences > System pane (see [Duarte's Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/98366)) But you could also try increasing the Anisotropic Filtering value (which basically means that the texture will be averaged more in the short direction than the long direction). This is a more expensive calculation but will achieve the de-graining of mipmapping without the blurriness.