# Mip mapping in cycles - how to showcase the effect?

Tags: customization

Can anyone make up a scene to showcase the mip-mapping in the blender user preferences for texture filtering? I couldn't find a scenario where switching it on/off made any difference in memory usage (apparently around 33%).

Cheers.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47943/how-to-render-a-model-with-pixel-art-sprite-textures-and-have-it-not-be-blurry and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98365/texture-blurry-when-viewed-at-shallow-angle/

Comment: ah so it's only relevant in the viewport and not in rendermode? Do you know about the texture timeout by any chance? I checked the Blender user guide but it doesn't help much. Is there any incentive to change the timeout values? Big ups btw, thanks for the help.